# integer(0) when plotting a shapefile and points

Tags: r, plot, spatial

I am plotting points over a shapefile and R keeps printing "integer(0)" after it completes the command. It plots fine, which can be seen in this reproducible example (with jarring colors because FUN=had ;-) )

```
### get Germany as shp
Germany.shp<-getData("GADM", country="DEU",level=1,download=T,path=getwd())
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(Germany.shp, col="magenta", main="plots normally")

### make up some spatial points (yes, the proper cities in Germany)
points.df<-data.frame(name=c("Berlin","Frankfurt","Rostock"),
                      lat=c(52.5243700,50.1155200,54.0887000), long=c(13.4105300,8.6841700,12.1404900))
coordinates(points.df)=~long+lat ### converts df to spatial df 
crs(points.df)<-CRS("+init=epsg:4326") ### defines CRS
points.df<-spTransform(points.df,crs(Germany.shp)) ### project to same CRS as Germany.shp

### plot
plot(Germany.shp, col="magenta", sub="is 0 actually in integer? just asking",main="integer 0",)+ 
  points(points.df,col="blue", pch=16,cex=2.2)

### !!! ### CONSOLE shows integer(0), plots perfectly well though ### !!! ###
```

I was really worried initially, since I am plotting 35000 points in my actual dataset. So I made up this example to cross-check and the cities are in the right place. However I am using a markdown and have 10-15 plots like this and thus have to manually delete the "integer(0)" console output manually. **annoying** ;)

Comment: You can add an `invisible({<plotting_code>})` wrapping your code, which will prevent any outputs from being shown. As you're using Rmarkdown, you could also set the chunk options to `results='hide'` so its outputs are not displayed in the rendered document.

Comment: I just simply added b<-myplot. Then R doesn't print the integer(0) but plots and chunk settings do not have to be changed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be several solutions.

easiest is to add your plot() to an object:

```
x<-plot()
```

Others have suggested wrapping it in `invisible()` or adjusting markdown settings to `results="hide"`

But making your plots into objects (imo) allows most flexibility and the opportunity to arrange the objects later so that you can plot them agian!